# XPath produces garbled output instead of Unicode characters

Tags: java, jvm

I am parsing this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<tests>
    <test category="Русский"/>
    <test category="ελληνικά"/>
    <test category="中文"/>
    <test category="English"/>
</tests>
```

Main class is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class TestUnicode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression lolwhy = xpath.compile("//test");
        final InputSource inputSource =
                new InputSource(
                new FileInputStream(
                new File("sample.xml")));
        NodeList parent = (NodeList) lolwhy.evaluate(
                inputSource,
                XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println(parent.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(parent.item(i).getAttributes().
                    getNamedItem("category").getNodeValue());
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
4
???????
????????
??
English
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: ok, this issue was related to [hebrew appears as question marks in netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/662146/362721) and the solution is this: [Setting the default Java character encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding/623036#623036)

Comment: Your Java console doesn't understand the encoding of the text sent to it. Try writing your output to a text file and reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that the parsing is ok, but the output is wrong.

If you you used a font that doesn't contain those characters, or if you output the values to HTML, but specify a wrong encoding, this can be the result.

The font-issue being the more likely one.

Comment: Yes, seems to be some kind of console output problem in Netbeans, but funny thing is - it seem to print garbage no matter what font i use.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println is the culprit.
See if this helps

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050208053951714

Comment: Thanks, but PrintStream workaround only prints:
4
Ð ÑƒÑ�Ñ�ÐºÐ¸Ð¹
ÎµÎ»Î»Î·Î½Î¹ÎºÎ¬
ä¸­æ–‡
English